# Picture doesn't show when using a variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie with JavaScript and I have the following code:
With the last two rows I tried to publish the picture, but it is not showing.
I'd like to know, what is wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var kaart = new Array(4);
    kaart[0] = "Achterkant";
    kaart[1] = "De Krijger";
    kaart[2] = "De Geliefde";
    kaart[3] = "De boodschapper";

    var plaatje = new Array(4);
    plaatje[0] = "kaart0.jpg" ;
    plaatje[1] = "kaart1.jpg" ;
    plaatje[2] = "kaart2.jpg" ;
    plaatje[3] = "kaart3.jpg" ;

    var rand; //random kaartnummer
    rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1
    document.body.innerHTML = "";
    document.write("De random kaart is: " + rand + "<br>");

    document.write("De kaart is " + plaatje[rand] + "<br>");
    document.images.src=(plaatje[rand]);

</script>
```

Comment: Where is your "images"?

Comment: `document.images` is a list of image tags. Does it work if you replace the last line with `document.images[0].src=plaatje[rand];`?

Comment: Maybe it's because you clear the page with `document.body.innerHTML = "";`? Side note: you'll overshoot the image array approx. 25% of the time (`rand` is between 1 and 4 but the array keys are between 0 and 3).

Comment: @hicurin: my images are in the same folder.

Comment: @RemcoHaszing: I tried your solution, but that doesn't work either. What was the meaning of [0] before the src?

Comment: @Juhana: I put that row to refresh the page, but I de-activated it with the same results.

Comment: It isn't the solution, but one of the bugs in the code you provided. `document.images` is a list of image tags, so you should probably set the `src` attribute of one of its elements. It would be better to give your `img` tag an id and use `document.getElementById('someid').src=(plaatje[rand]);` instead. Setting `document.body.innerHTML=""` removes all content from your page. Using `document.write` overwrites the entire webpage, use `document.getElementById('anotherid')` instead. Combining my advice and the advice of Juhana I think you should be able to fix it.

Comment: `document.images` is a list of all the images *already* on the page. If you don't already have any images on the page it won't work (you can't change the `src` of something that doesn't exist). You have to either have one image in the document, or add a new one.

Answer (score 1):

You are incrementing the array by 1 to many as the array is zero based. Changing this line:

```
rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1
```

to

```
rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
```

Fixes this.

You also need to remove the line `document.body.innerHTML = ""` as this is clearing your page content, removing all HTML from the body of the page.

And set the `document.image` to be the image you are targeting, either by it's position on the page `document.image[0]` or by it's id `document.getElementById('imgID')`.

Comment: Solid advice, but doesn't fix the actual problem.

Comment: Sorry, I posted before answering the whole question. Please see my revised answer.

Comment: @Jonathan: So I have to add an imgID to every picture like: plaatje[0] = "kaart0.jpg" img id="kaart0" ;?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to do: test the document.images statement or the random method, or preloading images.  Any rate.

1) document.images requires images...if there are none in the html, there is no image collection.
2) You need to create the html image tags before using document.images

```
plaatje[0] = "<image src='\images\kaart0.jpg'....;
```

3) if you are going to use body instead of a div
document.body.innerHTML += "De random kaart is: " + rand + "
";
but a div is much, much better

Is this what you are looking for?

```
<body>
<div id="myPic"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

var kaart = new Array(4);
kaart[0] = "Achterkant";
kaart[1] = "De Krijger";
kaart[2] = "De Geliefde";
kaart[3] = "De boodschapper";

var plaatje = new Array(4);
plaatje[0] = "somePic.jpg" ;
plaatje[1] = "www.example.com/images/dj71.jpg" ;
plaatje[2] = "kaart2.jpg" ;
plaatje[3] = "kaart3.jpg" ;
var rand; //random kaartnummer
rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);


var imgStr = "<img src='" +plaatje[rand] + "'/>"

var picDiv = document.getElementById('myPic');
picDiv.innerHTML += "De random kaart is: " + rand + "<br>";
picDiv.innerHTML += "De kaart is " + imgStr + "<br>";


  </script>

     </body>
```

Comment: I like to implement the random method. Do you have any suggestions to that?